# Marking automatically moved to folders (using rules) messages as Unread in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have some rules set up in Outlook 2010 that automatically move specific messages to specific folders as the applicable email arrives.

Ideally, I want these moved messages to show up in the folders as `Unread` to allow me to more easily spot when the messages arrive since the folder in question would be bold.

I was doing this with Outlook 2007 okay. However, in Outlook 2010, the messages get automatically moved as they should - but they are moved as `Read` messages so I don't realize there are new emails in certain folders that I have not yet seen.

How can I make messages that automatically move to specific folders using rules, to show up in the folders as `Unread` instead of `Read`?

Answer (score 3):

Something is broken or maybe just incorrectly configured.

Messages will be moved in the state they are already in (ie read or unread). You can explicitly include a step in your rules to mark them as read, but not vice-versa. 
Can you edit your rule to check that it is not set to mark as read every time?

Does it make a difference if the target folder is a sub-folder of your inbox (I have several set up this way and they work fine) or if it just a folder under the root of your mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is misconfigured, Outlook 2010 does this. It's hard to replicate, but I think it only occurs when your rule moves the mail item to the folder it's already in. With this VBA you can force your rule to mark the item as unread.

```
Sub unread(MyItem As MailItem)
MyItem.unread = True
End Sub
```

Choose "and run a script" in the rule options and select the above.